# Comments too chatty

Tags: discussion, flags

I have a question about what happens if I flagged some comments as "too chatty".

I have posted an answer and one person became too chatty which is very irritating and I flagged his comments as "too chatty", but nothing happened. Why?

If a moderator is not attending this flag then what is other solution for this?

And if moderator delete flagged comments, is that person get the notification ?

[image]

Comment: *When* did you flag the comments? What is the status in your flag history (link on your profile)? The moderator flag queue is *huge* and I can imagine that 'too chatty' comments are not being prioritised.

Comment: @MartijnPieters yes it is helpful now but what happend when moderator delete some comments, is that person get the notification ?

Comment: No, when comments are deleted no one is notified.

Comment: So thats the problem how would the person know not to be too chatty?

Comment: *Is* the person being too chatty? That's not that big problem, is it? Just ignore and move on.

Comment: and if he is forcing the op to mark his answer as accepted by commenting then what?

Comment: You cannot force anyone to do anything. *Just ignore and move on*.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Your option is to take a chill pill and move on to another question.

If someone is being pesky through the comments your best option is to simply ignore them. Maybe leave one last comment to tell them that you are disengaging from the conversation, but just quit and walk away from it. Don't feed the troll.

When the mods get to your flags they will delete them as appropriate.

Comment: when moderator delete that is that person will get some kind of notification so that he can't do nexttime?

Comment: No, I don't believe they do. Comments are considered to be second class citizens, there's no formality around deleting them.

Comment: Good answer. But you should clarify that in many countries, one would need a subscription for that particular kind of pill. ;)

Comment: I would actually discourage you from even commenting to say that you're not commenting.  It doesn't do anyone any good (nobody is better off for having read such a comment), and can often do even more harm by aggravating the other user(s).